# How to trigger the loop after it finish it fully finish executing a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, automation

I created a small bot that I intended to loop on all that are listed on the list and scrape data from a it that is on the other page. So I just utilize iframe so I can override and grab data from it.

the problem with my script is  it's returning duplicate records in my console.log. What It supposed to do is to grab a data from another page and store it on the parent page. For now I just use `console.log` to see what it's returning. And then may be later I'll be storing them on a `<textarea>` so I can easily copy it or store it on a file.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>While Looping</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">


            var list = [ 644, 464, 441, 442, 552, 444, 594, 487, 430, 545, 524, 500, 450, 626, 505, 466, 456, 418, 560, 507, 535, 417, 462, 424, 551, 590, 453, 595, 593, 423, 495, 484, 536, 421, 518, 563, 515, 556, 532, 488, 465, 600, 597, 498, 534, 513, 514, 530, 519, 443, 596, 631, 533, 422, 437, 576, 504, 502, 361, 448, 598, 544, 416, 617, 537, 477, 447, 539, 614, 557, 445, 630, 588, 632, 476, 439, 574, 523, 636, 461, 558, 359, 499, 440, 481, 643, 460, 470, 569, 425, 573, 620, 615, 475, 468, 543, 599, 612, 613, 452, 582, 618, 455, 525, 438, 471, 628, 511, 562, 564, 565, 566, 605, 467, 463, 529, 561, 436, 527, 547, 623, 606, 486, 482, 555, 446, 559, 548, 549, 550, 607, 405, 540, 469, 474, 629, 611, 426, 639, 493, 602, 349, 604, 622, 546, 492, 494, 567, 407, 420, 399, 496, 531, 491, 520, 521, 404, 586, 459, 479, 637, 570, 634, 608, 584, 638, 601, 508, 516, 480, 571, 610, 621, 512, 483, 587, 592, 627, 642, 589, 428, 403, 541, 542, 625, 517, 522, 432, 497, 526, 644, 464, 441, 442, 552, 444, 594, 487, 430, 545, 524, 500, 450, 626, 505, 466, 456, 418, 560, 507, 535, 417, 462, 424, 551, 590, 453, 595, 593, 423, 495, 484, 536, 421, 518, 563, 515, 556, 532, 488, 465, 600, 597, 498, 534, 513, 514, 530, 519, 443, 596, 631, 533, 422, 437, 576, 504, 502, 361, 448, 598, 544, 416, 617, 537, 477, 447, 539, 614, 557, 445, 630, 588, 632, 476, 439, 574, 523, 636, 461, 558, 359, 499, 440, 481, 643, 460, 470, 569, 425, 573, 620, 615, 475, 468, 543, 599, 612, 613, 452, 582, 618, 455, 525, 438, 471, 628, 511, 562, 564, 565, 566, 605, 467, 463, 529, 561, 436, 527, 547, 623, 606, 486, 482, 555, 446, 559, 548, 549, 550, 607, 405, 540, 469, 474, 629, 611, 426, 639, 493, 602, 349, 604, 622, 546, 492, 494, 567, 407, 420, 399, 496, 531, 491, 520, 521, 404, 586, 459, 479, 637, 570, 634, 608, 584, 638, 601, 508, 516, 480, 571, 610, 621, 512, 483, 587, 592, 627, 642, 589, 428, 403, 541, 542, 625, 517, 522, 432, 497, 526, 616, 575, 585, 509, 554, 506, 454, 501, 431, 434, 603, 640, 641, 489, 451, 472, 510, 490, 473, 458, 457, 609, 568, 478, 619, 553, 538, 427, 635, 624, 583, 591, 572, 633, 429, 419, 503, 485, 435, 433, 528, 449, 340, 616, 575, 585, 509, 554, 506, 454, 501, 431, 434, 603, 640, 641, 489, 451, 472, 510, 490, 473, 458, 457, 609, 568, 478, 619, 553, 538, 427, 635, 624, 583, 591, 572, 633, 429, 419, 503, 485, 435, 433, 528, 449, 340 ];

            var count = 0;
            var total_list = list.length;
            var page_id;
            var base_url = "http://somewebsite.com/iframe_path";

            var iframe_url = base_url + page_id;


            function load_data() {


                $("#iframe").load(function() {


                    var acc_name = $("#iframe").contents().find("#text_name").attr("value");

                    var acc_add = $("#iframe").contents().find("#text'_address").attr("value");

                    setTimeout(nextFrame, 1000);

                    console.log( list[count] + ' ' + acc_name + ' ' + acc_add );


                });

                $("h1").text(count);

            } //load data

            // loop records
            function nextFrame() {
                if(count != total_list) {
                    var iframe_url = base_url+list[count];
                    $("#iframe").attr('src',iframe_url);

                    console.log(iframe_url);


                    load_data();
                    count++;
                    //Continue the loop in 3s
                    //setTimeout(nextFrame, 1000);
                }
            }
            // Start the loop
            setTimeout(nextFrame, 0);


        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>0</h1> <br />

    <iframe width="400" height="400" id="iframe"></iframe>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's returning duplicate for console.log( list[count] + ' ' + acc_name + ' ' + acc_add );

Comment: try putting it before the `setTimeout`.

Comment: so the result look something like this.

Hotel Name A California | Hotel Name B New York Hotel Name B New York | Hotel Name C Las Vegas Hotel Name C Las Vegas Hotel Name C Las Vegas Hotel Name C Las Vegas

Comment: As you can see the results keeps duplicating it self.

Comment: ian's answer is correct. every time the script runs you re-bind the function to load, so it logs it one more time.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you re-binding "onload" for the iframe? Everytime you call load_data(), it binds another event to the iframe to run the specified function when it loads. Try something like this:

```
        var list = [ 644, 464, 441, 442 ];

        var count = 0;
        var total_list = list.length;
        var page_id;
        var base_url = "http://somewebsite.com/iframe_path";

        var iframe_url = base_url + page_id;


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#iframe").load(function() {
                var acc_name = $("#iframe").contents().find("#text_name").attr("value");

                var acc_add = $("#iframe").contents().find("#text'_address").attr("value");

                console.log( list[count] + ' ' + acc_name + ' ' + acc_add );

                setTimeout(nextFrame, 1000);
            });
        });

        // loop records
        function nextFrame() {
            if(count != total_list) {
                var iframe_url = base_url+list[count];
                $("#iframe").attr('src',iframe_url);

                console.log(iframe_url);

                count++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You'll probably have to do a little tweaking because the load function will run on page load because the iframe is loaded at the start. And I'm sure I didn't get your whole "count" stuff correctly, but it's just an example anyways...